# Parallel API requests using Spark and pyspark

Tags: api, apache-spark, pyspark, async-await, python-asyncio

I am doing this below thing to do API request using EMR cluster:

```
def get_normal_objects(self,object_name, get_id, chunk_size=35,**params):
    contacts_pages = []
    batch = 0
    while True:
        urls = ["{}/{}".format(self.base_url, "{}?page={}&api_key={}".format(object_name, page_number, self.api_keys))
                for page_number in range(batch * chunk_size + 1, chunk_size * (1 + batch) + 1)]

        responses_raw = self.get_responses(urls, self.office_token, chunk_size)
        LOGGER.info("Collecting data for {} for batch  {}".format(object_name, batch))

        try:
            responses_json = [json.loads(response_raw['output']) for response_raw in responses_raw]
```

The code will work fine when I extract the simple objects which do not need ids but it actually takes lots of time when it tries to extract the complex relational objects which require id first to hit the API :

```
"https://integrations.mydesktop.com.au/api/v1.2/properties/22028014/sales?api_key"

def get_complex_objects(self,object_name_1, object_name_2, ids,spark,  chunk_size=30, **params):
    results = []
    batch = 0

    while True:
        ids_start = batch * chunk_size + 1
        ids_end = chunk_size * (1 + batch) + 1
        chunk_ids = [ids[i] for i in range(ids_start, ids_end) if i < len(ids)]

        urls = [
            "{}/{}".format(self.base_url, "{}/{}/{}?api_key={}".format(object_name_1, contactId, object_name_2, self.api_keys))
            for contactId in chunk_ids]
        

        LOGGER.info("Collecting data for {}:{} for batch  {}".format(object_name_1, object_name_2, batch))
        responses_raw = self.get_responses(urls, self.office_token, chunk_size)
```

I am using the following get_response function to get the responses:

```
def get_responses(self, urls, office_token, chunk_size=30, **params):
    """Calls all the urls in parallel in bathes of {chuck_size}

    Arguments:
        urls {List} -- list of all urls to call
        office_token {String} -- Office token

    Keyword Arguments:
        chunk_size {int} -- nuber of parallel api calls (default: {30})

    Returns:
        [type] -- [description]
    """
    for chunk in list(mydesktop.chunks(urls, chunk_size)):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(self.__run(params, office_token, chunk))
        responses = loop.run_until_complete(future)

    return responses

async def __fetch(self, url, params, session):
  try:
    async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        #print('X-RateLimit-Remaining:{0}'.format(response.headers['X-RateLimit-Remaining']))
        output = await response.read()
        return output
  except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
    print(str(e))
    return None

async def __bound_fetch(self, sem, url, params, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        output = await self.__fetch(url, params, session)
        return {"url": url, "output":output}

async def __run(self, params, auth_user, urls):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(400)
    async with ClientSession(auth=BasicAuth(auth_user, password='', ),
                             connector=TCPConnector(ssl=False)) as session:
        for url in urls:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.__bound_fetch(sem, url, params, session))
            tasks.append(task)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return responses
```

My question is how can I utilize the parallelism feature of Spark and distribute the URLs into executors so that I can reduce the extraction time?

Was thinking to use urls = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(urls) to send URLs to executors then use map lambda to do the get request.

Comment: don't understand why you try this with spark.

Comment: We are not using Spark at the moment, but since the extraction takes a lot of time even with asyncio so was wondering if we can reduce it with Spark as we can take advantage of using multiple executors to hit to the same task

Comment: If my get_Response function can get improved I am open to that too.

Comment: Hi jack. did you achieve your goal using Spark?